# Website font correction

Tags: fonts, blogs

I was changing fonts and their line-heights for my site. But I forgot the original settings and I don't know now if my site's fonts and their line-heights are fine and relative or not. Here is a sample article about [Blogging earning](http://howbees.com/2013/04/23/how-to-make-money-blogging/). you can check all fonts here h1 h2 and p.

Please have a look and let me know if what needs to be set, the font size or line height.
Thanks

Comment: provide a fiddle for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the website reference that you have provided, you need to set font-size and line-height both. Below are the settings for h1, h2 and p

```
h1{font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 38px;}

h2{font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 28px;}

p{font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 25px;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok great! Thank you very much. Most of mine are same except h1. I'll change it. Thans again for your help!